# Inverse of a matrix

Tags: covariance, matrix

I have a variance covariance matrix $n \times n$ $$V = \sigma^2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \rho & \rho & ... & \rho \\ \rho & 1 & \rho & ... & \rho \\ ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \rho &\rho & \rho & ... & 1\end{pmatrix} $$ where $\rho$ is the correlation coefficient and I write it as $$V =\sigma^2 [ (1-\rho)I_n + \rho J_n ] $$ where $I_n$ is the identity matrix and $J_n$ is a matrix with 1s. I want to show that the inverse matrix is $$V^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \Bigg[ \frac{J_n}{n[1+(n-1)\rho]} + \frac{1}{1-\rho}\Big( I_n  - \frac{1}{n}J_n \Big)  \Bigg] $$
How can I show that? Thank you...

Comment: Use [Sherman-Morrison-Woodburry formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).

Comment: $B$ is an inverse of square matrix $A$ if and only if $BA = I$

Comment: Zhanxiong, thank you very much. I used this and I solved it.

Comment: @BadJohn If you've solved it, you can write an answer explaining what you've done, which means that (1) this question will no longer be unanswered and (2) you can accumulate reputation from the answer.

Comment: The simplest solution is to multiply the putative inverse times $V$: if you arrive at the identity matrix, *QED*.

Answer (score 1):

Since for an invertible matrix $M$ and a scalar $\lambda \neq 0$, the inverse of $\lambda M$ is $\lambda^{-1}M$, it suffices to treat the case $\sigma=1$. A useful identity is $J_n^2=nJ_n$. Denote 
$$
a= \frac{1}{n[1+(n-1)\rho]} - \frac{1}{n(1-\rho)   }  ; b=\frac 1{1-\rho}
$$
We have to prove that 
$$
(aJ_n+bI_n)\left((1-\rho)I_n+\rho J_n\right)=I_n.
$$
Expanding the left hand side gives 
$$
(aJ_n+bI_n)\left((1-\rho)I_n+\rho J_n\right)= a(1-\rho) J_n+a\rho nJ_n+b(1-\rho)I_n+b\rho J_n
$$
and since $b(1-\rho)=1$, this reduces to 
$$
(aJ_n+b)\left((1-\rho)I_n+\rho J_n\right)=I_n+\left(a(1-\rho)+a\rho n+b\rho \right)J_n.
$$
Since 
$$
a(1-\rho)+a\rho n=a\left(1+(n-1)\rho\right)=\frac 1n-\frac{1+(n-1)\rho}{n(1-\rho)}
,$$
we get 
$$
a(1-\rho)+a\rho n+b\rho =\frac 1n+\frac{-1-(n-1)\rho+n\rho}{n(1-\rho)}=0.
$$