# Variance of sum of dependent random variables

Tags: machine-learning, probability, correlation, variance, prediction

Can you guys help me prove the following:

$$
\operatorname{Var}\left[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^my_i\right]=\frac{1}{m}(1-\rho)\sigma^2+\rho\sigma^2
$$

where the sampled predictions ($y_is$) have variance $\sigma^2$ and correlation $\rho$.

Note: $y_is$ are NOT independent. We have a dependent sample.

Comment: One method is to write the variance-covariance matrix in the form given in the question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257722/inverse-of-a-matrix#comment729432_257722.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's quite easy to prove this once you understand the relationship between the covariance and correlation and if you recognize that the variances for both $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ are identically $\sigma^2$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
V\left[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y_{i}\right] & = & \frac{1}{m^{2}}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{m}V(y_{i})+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{i\ne j}^{m}Cov(y_{i},y_{j})\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{m^{2}}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sigma^{2}+\sigma^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{i\ne j}^{m}\frac{Cov(y_{i},y_{j})}{\sigma^{2}}\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{m^{2}}\left[m\sigma^{2}+\sigma^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{i\ne j}^{m}\rho\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{m^{2}}\left[m\sigma^{2}+\sigma^{2}(m^{2}-m)\rho\right]\\
 & = & \frac{\sigma^{2}}{m}+\frac{\sigma^{2}(m-1)\rho}{m}\\
 & = & \frac{\sigma^{2}}{m}+\frac{\sigma^{2}\rho m}{m}-\frac{\sigma^{2}\rho}{m}\\
 & = & \frac{\sigma^{2}-\sigma^{2}\rho}{m}+\rho\sigma^{2}\\
 & = & \frac{\left(1-\rho\right)\sigma^{2}}{m}+\rho\sigma^{2}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{m}\left(1-\rho\right)\sigma^{2}+\rho\sigma^{2}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\blacksquare
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: This is a very rigorous and detailed derivation, thank you!! Just what I wanted :)

Comment: @StatsPupil, the way to indicate that this answers fulfills your needs is by clicking the accept check mark button next to the answer itself. This incentive will encourage others to answer your questions in the future.  Thank you.

Comment: @StatsPupil.  Absolutely.  That's what some of us more experienced users are here for.  We try to help out some of the newcomers! Best of luck to you!

Comment: What is X for this question?

Comment: @Kuo, I think I got sloppy with the notation and substituted $X_i$, and $X_j$ for $Y$.  I'll correct this.  Thanks for catching this.